# didSelectRowAtIndexPath don't navigate to destinationView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a UITableView as a childView in another view called ViewController and in UITableView I want that the cell will be clickable and navigate to destinationView without using storyBoard so I implemented this code on my didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  NSLog(@"helloWorld!");
  DescriptionViewController *desc = [[DescriptionViewController alloc]
  initWithNibName:@"DescriptionViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:desc animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Since you're not using Storyboards are you sure you have set up the parent UINavigationController correctly? It would help to show your code for the navigation controller.

Comment: check self.navigationController is nil or not ?

Comment: self.navigationController return nil

Comment: try [self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:desc animated:YES];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly you have a nil navigation

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:desc animated:YES];
```

so make sure that the current VC is embedded inside a navigation Controller

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    MainViewController *main = [[MainViewController alloc ] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController*nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:main];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;

    return YES;
}
```

[image]

If you don't even use xibs , then load the vc like this

```
DescriptionViewController*desc = [[DescriptionViewController alloc] init];
```

To replace:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = desc;
```

Comment: if I put this an exception appear
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </UsersSubViewProject.app> (loaded)' with name 'DescriptionViewController''

Comment: you should have a nib names DescriptionViewController.xib if you don;t use storyboards , see edit i suppose the vc you push from is MainViewController and it has a nib also

Comment: Thanks that work but it keeps the old ViewContoller or I want when I click on the cell it navigate to anotherView not just change the subView  by the new view(DescriptionViewContoller)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your `navigationController` is not nil, and instantiate the view controller object to push.

**1. Check Navigation( from storyboard):**

[image]

**2. Instantiate view-controller:**

```
DescriptionViewController *desc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DescriptionViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:desc animated:YES];
```

*If you have more than 1 storyboard in your project, you can use,*

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
DescriptionViewController *desc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DescriptionViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:desc animated:YES];
```

[image]

**3. If your view is not on storyboard**

Just initialize and push to DescriptionViewController,

```
DescriptionViewController *desc = [[DescriptionViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:desc animated:YES];
```

and in `viewDidLoad` of `DescriptionViewController`, add a white view to load.

```
UIView *whiteView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)];
whiteView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:whiteView];
```

Comment: Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x7fddb1019a00>.

Comment: You need to provide the identifier to your view controller in storyboard **"DescriptionViewController"**.

Comment: thnx but I said that I'm not using storyBoard I'm writing everything programmatically

Comment: In that you can simply use `DescriptionViewController *desc = [[DescriptionViewController alloc] init];`

Comment: yes thats the problem I initialise with a nib or there is no Nib file thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

> If your view controller is embedded inside a `UINavigationController` then the below code will work:
>
> ```
> [self.navigationController pushViewController:desc animated:YES];
> ```
>
> Else you will have to present your view controller modally like below:
>
> ```
> [self presentViewController:desc animated:YES completion:nil];
> ```

Comment: if I comment [self presentViewController:desc animated:YES completion:nil]; that doesn't work but if I comment [self.navigationController pushViewController:desc animated:YES]; and work only with the presentViewController it work can you explain please

Comment: @ElyMan To push view controller, you need to have a `UINavigationController`. UINavigationController maintains the stack of the view controllers. If the view controller is not embedded inside a UINavigationController, you will not be able to push another view controller on it but you can present it modally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the stack structure i.e Parent controller is embedded inside the UINavigationController, try the below code snippet:

```
DescriptionViewController *desc = [[DescriptionViewController alloc]
                              initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([DescriptionViewController class]) bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:desc animated:YES];
```

If you want to present the DescriptionViewController modally and add a Navigation Controller to it, the following code snippet will be useful

```
DescriptionViewController *desc = [[DescriptionViewController alloc]
                                       initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([DescriptionViewController class]) bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCtr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: desc];
[self presentViewController:navCtr animated:YES completion:nil];
```